# Français vs anglais (infinitif vs participe présent)

Tags: grammaire, traduction, syntaxe

Je sais que la question est plutôt vaste. Mais je me demande depuis toujours. 
Il me suffit une réponse brève ou même encore des références en ligne.

Pourquoi existe-t-il cette grande différence syntaxique ? Par exemple :

> Sans donner = Without giving

En français la préposition est suivie par l'infinitif tandis qu'en anglais elle est suivie par le participe présent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pourquoi deux expressions en deux langues seraient-elles identiques ? ;)

Le lien qui les unit est qu'à travers les langues européennes, ce sont l'infinitif et les participes qui ont toujours tendance à se comporter comme des noms. Or ce qui suit normalement *sans* ou *without* doit être un group nominal : "sans (auc)un bruit", "without a sound". Les rôles à jouer sont donc semblables.

En anglais le participe remplit tant de fonctions que remplit l'infinitif en français :

> We're going swimming. *On va nager.*
>
> Praying isn't always easy. *Prier n'est pas toujours facile.*
>
> I don't like eating at McDonald's. *Je n'aime pas manger à McDo.*

Les possibilités se chevauchent parfois, mais je crois que le participe serait ici un anglicisme. (De toute façon ceci n'est pas un emploi nominal.)

> I saw her drinking / drink coffee yesterday.
>
> Je l'ai vue boire / buvant / qui buvait du café hier.

L'explication de cette préférence de la part de l'anglais m'échappe. En allemand par exemple c'est l'infinitif et non le participe qui remplit ces fonctions, comme en français.

Comment: Voici une réponse qui mérite la caractérisation superbe ! Bravo !

Comment: Tu as raison (je crois pouvoir tutoyer:-)!)  par rapport la question "pourquoi...". Je m'étais demande mais je pensais toujours aux tournures de type sans parler, sans manger etc. Grâce à toi je vois le sujet plus globalement. Merci encore.

Comment: En effet la correspondance (entre infinitif-participé présent) n'est pas toujours vraie. On dit sans parler; avant d'entrer = without speaking; before going in mais pour réussir = in order to succed.

Comment: En plus, Ne pas se pencher = do not lean out, or s'adresser au concierge  = apply to the porter.

Comment: Bonnes observations. Je dirais que l'infinitif en anglais correspond très normalement à l'infinitif en français ; c'est l'autre sens qui subit plus de variations.